# How does Cosmos DB Continuation Token work?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

At first sight, it's clear what the continuation token does in Cosmos DB: attaching it to the next query gives you the next set of results. But what does "next set of results" mean exactly?

Does it mean:

1. the next set of results as if the original query had been executed completely without paging at the time of the very first query (skipping the appropriate number of documents)?
2. the next set of results as if the original query had been executed now (skipping the appropriate number of documents)?
3. Something completely different?

---

Answer 1. would seem preferable but unlikely given that the server would need to store unlimited amounts of state. But Answer 2. is also problematic as it may result in inconsistencies, e.g. the same document may be served multiple times across pages, if the underlying data has changed between the page queries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cosmos DB query executions are stateless at the server side. The continuation token is used to recreate the state of the index and track progress of the execution.

"Next set of results" means, the query is executed again on from a "bookmark" from the previous execution. This bookmark is provided by the continuation token.

1. Documents created during continuations

They may or may not be returned depending on the position of insert and query being executed.

**Example:**

SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.someValue ASC

Let us assume the bookmark had someValue = 10, the query engine resumes processing using a continuation token where someValue = 10.

If you were to insert a new document with someValue = 5 in between query executions, it **will not show up** in the next set of results.

If the new document is inserted in a "page" that is > the bookmark, it **will show up** in next set of results

2. Documents updated during continuations

Same logic as above applies to updates as well
(See #4)

3. Documents deleted during continuations

They **will not show up** in the next set of results.

4. Chances of duplicates

In case of the below query,

SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.remainingInventory ASC

If the remainingInventory was updated after the first set of results and it now satisfies the ORDER BY criteria for the second page, the document **will show up** again.

---

Cosmos DB doesn’t provide snapshot isolation across query pages.
However, as per the product team this is an incredibly uncommon scenario because queries over continuations are very quick and in most cases all query results are returned on the first page.

Comment: Thank you, that's already helpful to know that new items are not included, so option #2 above can be excluded. But it's still not a complete specification of what "next set of results" means. Obviously the information encoded in the continuation token does not suffice to recreate the entire index (otherwise it may grow as large as the entire collection), and no state is stored server-side, so some information is lost and option #1 is not feasible.

Do intermittent deletes become observable? Intermittent updates?

Comment: I could not confirm your statement that items created after the first page are not included on subsequent pages. I used Sacha Bruttin's Cosmos DB Explorer to query all documents with a page size of 1 (ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb is not set), and by retrieving pages one by one, I eventually observed all documents created between the single page requests. Also, deletes and updates between page requests were always observable on subsequent pages. This suggests that option #2 is true.

Comment: The continuation token is used to construct the entire state of the index. That's why the token can grow more than 12K and as you rightly pointed out, larger than the document itself is certain situations. Some clients have limitations on the length(size) of the token received in the http header. So the option of  ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb was introduced. By limiting the token size, you still talk to Cosmos but since it doesn't have all the data it needs to serialize the state it now needs to scan the index again and hence, new additions, deletions, changed data is also returned.

Comment: Its been a while I worked on issues with continuation tokens, let me research this a bit more and update my findings here. I will use the Cosmos DB Explorer as well.

Comment: Thanks, that would be really helpful. Just to clarify: in my experiment, the token size was not limited by ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb, and yet all intermediate writes (creates, updates, deletes) were observable on subsequent pages.

Comment: Oh, and Cross Partition Queries were enabled.

Comment: I have updated the answer with all scenarios after contacting the product team. I hope that answers your questions

Comment: Great answer. That explains my experimental findings. Please relay to the product team that the need for transactional reads is far from esoteric for backend applications. In fact, Cosmos DB's lack of read transactions somewhat makes its support for write transactions less useful, since you can't avoid reading transactionally inconsistent states.

Comment: So in other words, continuation token does not guarantee the latest results will be returned for the next batch because of the way how it works.

Comment: When paging with a relational database we *should* order the results prior to skipping and taking a section of the table. In your examples I see you're using `ORDER BY`; should we be ordering the documents prior to paging for non relation databases as well?

Answer (score 3):

Based on preliminary experiments, the answer seems to be option #2, or more precisely:

1. Documents created after serving the first page are observable on subsequent pages
2. Documents updated after serving the first page are observable on subsequent pages
3. Documents deleted after serving the first page are omitted on subsequent pages
4. Documents are never served twice

The first statement above contradicts information from MSFT (*cf.* Kalyan's answer). It would be great to get a more qualified answer from the Cosmos DB Team specifying precisely the semantics of retrieving pages. This may not be very important for displaying data in the UI, but may be essential for data processing in the backend, given that there doesn't seem to be any way of *disabling* paging when performing a query (*cf.* [Are transactional queries possible in Cosmos DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540302/are-transactional-queries-possible-in-cosmos-db)).

---

### Experimental method

I used Sacha Bruttin's [Cosmos DB Explorer](https://github.com/sachabruttin/CosmosDbExplorer) to query a collection with 5 documents, because this tool allows playing around with the page size and other request options.

The page size was set to 1, and Cross Partition Queries were enabled. Different queries were tried, e.g. `SELECT * FROM c` or `SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.name`.

After retrieving page 1, new documents were inserted, and some existing documents (including documents that should appear on subsequent pages) were updated and deleted. Then all subsequent pages were retrieved in sequence.

(A quick look at the source code of the tool confirmed that `ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb` is not set.)

Comment: I am sure I had run into the issue of new documents not getting returned some time back. Found one such issue here that talks about the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216251/cosmos-db-continuation-token-size-influences-whether-query-returns-new-documents/54242859#54242859 Let me try and get in touch with someone from the Cosmos team and confirm this

Comment: To your comment on disabling paging, you can set the MaxItemCount property in FeedOptions to a high number (upto 1000) to get more results per page

Comment: You can set MaxItemCount to get larger pages, but the point is that you can't use it to avoid paging altogether, so there doesn't seem to be a way to do a query in a transactional manner.

Comment: Great work. This matches what we might expect: a continuation token does not expire, and supporting consistent snapshots in an unbounded way would require an unbounded amount of storage. As such, newer changes do show up. On top of that, the token stores information to avoid serving a document twice (which would otherwise happen if it was changed such that it appears _further down_ the index used).